# Enable/Disable Sql Server Agent using a t-sql script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

Is it possible to enable or disable the sql server agent using t-sql?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = 'Job Name', @enabled = 0 --Disable
exec msdb..sp_update_job @job_name = 'Job Name', @enabled = 1 --Enable
```

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to enable/disable the agent itself too?

Comment: You're welcome!  And yes, google xp_servicecontrol (I've never use it).

Answer (score 7):

You can use this to set it ON or OFF

```
   EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'stop',N'SQLServerAGENT'
   EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'start',N'SQLServerAGENT'
```